# How to determine a TSQL error is a runtime error or parse error?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to determine a TSQL error is a runtime error or parse error? For example, when I execute

```
asdf
```

I'll get

> Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 1 Could not find stored procedure
>   'asdf'.

When I execute

```
asdf sdf asdf
```

I'll get

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1 Incorrect syntax near 'asdf'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the level to differentiate between different kinds of errors. See this for description of error levels: [Database Engine Error Severities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164086%28SQL.90%29.aspx).

If you need to you can also use the error messages which are listed in `sys.messages` but keep in mind that there are about 9000 different possible messages.

Comment: Why has this been accepted? It doesn't answer the question "How to determine a TSQL error is a runtime error or parse error?" at all. The level is just the error severity.

Answer (score 3):

Batches with Parse Errors and Binding Errors will not generate an execution plan. Batches with Runtime errors will. Not sure if there is any other way of telling the source of the error.

```
/*Parse Error*/
SELEC * FROM master..spt_values

GO

/*Bind Error*/
SELECT * FROM master..spt_values_

GO

/*Runtime Error*/
SELECT 1/high FROM master..spt_values
```